# What use is only write permission on a folder?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

Given a linux directory with the following permissions:

```
d-w-------
```

Can the owner of this directory do anything with it?

cd returns Permission denied

touch c/file likewise

Are there any situations where this directory would be useful?

Comment: This answer specifically covers directory permissions in linux http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252

Comment: Thank you Gavin. As I understand, it's useless without the execute bit

Comment: It sure looks that way.